# Apple Sign In credentials like FirebaseAuth.instance

Tags: flutter, authentication, sign

I submit my app to App Store, first time and rejected because Apple Sign In doesn't include in app. I can add successfully apple sign in to my app, but I don't know how I use credentials.

How I use this informations e-mail and fullname like FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName! ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might start with the FlutterFire Authentication docs here (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/), which outline how to use the credentials object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.